# IntelliJ IDEA warns of "Unnecessary 'Arrays.asList' call"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
final SomeObjectType[] list = webserviceResponse.getArrayOfObjects();
    if (list != null) {
        final List<SomeObjectType> responseList = Arrays.asList(list);
        for (final SomeObjectType prt : responseList) {
            // doing some factory conversion.
        }
    }
```

IntelliJ IDEA is giving me the warning

> Unnecessary 'Arrays.asList' call

while I'm converting my array to a `List`. Why?

[image: link to image]

Can someone answer simply?

Comment: what's `list` ?

Comment: If IntelliJ means `responseList  = Collections.singletonList(list);` then the compile time class is not an array but some Object. Michel_T has a point.

Comment: sorry, added explanation to 'list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ warns you about that because you could simply do

```
if (list != null) {
    for (final SomeObjectType prt : list) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This works because arrays also have an iterator.